# how to order column for dataframe.expect method

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to achieve SQL MINUS behaviour in Spark and here is 2 JSON people1.json and people2.json with same data

```
{"name":"abc","age":22}
{"name":"xyz","age":20}
```

Spark Code

```
val dfpeople1 = spark.read.json("/tmp/people1.json")
val dfpeople2 = spark.read.json("/tmp/people2.json")

val dfDifference = dfpeople1.except(dfpeople2)

dfDifference.show()

##########dataframe dataframe (as expected)##########
+---+----+
|age|name|
+---+----+
+---+----+
```

Column name age in people2.json does not match this time (age coming as xage)

```
{"name":"abc","xage":22}
{"name":"xyz","xage":20}
```

Spark Code with column name renamed.

```
val dfpeople1 = spark.read.json("/tmp/people1.json")
val xdfpeople2 = spark.read.json("/tmp/people2.json")
val dfpeople2 = xdfpeople2.withColumnRenamed("xage","age")

val dfDifference = dfpeople1.except(dfpeople2)

dfpeople1.show()
dfpeople2.show()
dfDifference.show()

##########Output##########
*******people1 dataframe******    
+---+----+
|age|name|
+---+----+
| 22| abc|
| 20| xyz|
+---+----+

*******people2 dataframe******    
|name|age|
+----+---+
| abc| 22|
| xyz| 20|
+----+---+

*******dfDifference -> I want this to return 0 rows******       
+---+----+
|age|name|
+---+----+
| 20| xyz|
| 22| abc|
+---+----+
```

I want the final Dataframe to result as the previous result (0 rows). It is not coming up like that possibly due to Column order's!

Any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just select `dfpeople2` with the columns from `dfpeople1`

```
val dfpeople1 = spark.read.json("/tmp/people1.json")
val xdfpeople2 = spark.read.json("/tmp/people2.json")
val dfpeople2 = xdfpeople2.withColumnRenamed("xage","age")

val columns = dfpeople1.columns
val dfpeople2Ordered = dfpeople2.select(columns.head, columns.tail:_*)

val dfDifference = dfpeople1.except(dfpeople2Ordered)

dfpeople1.show()
dfpeople2.show()
dfpeople2Ordered.show()
dfDifference.show()


##########Output##########
*******people1 dataframe******    
+---+----+
|age|name|
+---+----+
| 22| abc|
| 20| xyz|
+---+----+

*******people2 dataframe******    
|name|age|
+----+---+
| abc| 22|
| xyz| 20|
+----+---+

*******dfpeople2Ordered dataframe******    
+---+----+
|age|name|
+---+----+
| 22| abc|
| 20| xyz|
+---+----+

*******dfDifference -> ******       
+---+----+
|age|name|
+---+----+
+---+----+
```